# Probability of generating two matching random numbers to 15 decimal places

Tags: statistics

In my app, I am capturing the duration of a user event in milliseconds to 15 decimal places.

1. I would like to know if a formula exists to calculate the probability of different user's duration matching any others to 15 decimal places.
2. Also, how many successive events would it take before a matching duration could occur?

Comment: This cannot be answered without much more information on the event.  Maybe it is very consistent and always takes 0.123456789012345ms so it is certain to match; okay, that is unlikely but it might be mostly within a small range.  Your clock might not be that accurate and maybe the last 5 or 10 digits are always 0; this is more likely.  Maybe it could span a large range but is mostly quick.  Etc.  Etc.

Comment: @badjohn, thanks.  The duration of the event is not consistent which is the reason for posing the question.  

I am trying to determine if a user executes an event with duration, t, what is the probability of some other user or the same user executing an event subsequently that matches duration, t, to 15 decimal places.  

For example, the event is a stopwatch event (begin/end) which is initiated by a mouse click and ends with the subsequent mouse click.  So, what is the probability that any subsequent begin/end click event's duration matches, t?  If you need more info, let me know.